# why my plugin is not working After shopware 6.4 upgradation?

Tags: symfony, shopware

[image]I am getting this error after when i use my pluign feature after upgrade my shopware6.4.
Before update my plugin was working perfectly fine.

Unable to load template "storefront/section/cms-section-half-width.html.twig". (Looked into: Framework, Profiling, Administration, Elasticsearch, FroshPlatformAdminer, UltraDeveloper, DneTemplateManager, DneCustomCssJs, Storefront)

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which was the old Shopware version? It means a template is referenced but not existing anymore. Anyways, I also cannot find this template (cms-section-half-width.html.twig) in 6.3.5. Do you create it yourself earlier?

Comment: Hello, Our team created this plugin, it was working with 6.3 now we upgraded into 6.4. since then its not working.

Comment: Which exact version of 6.3 did you work before? I suggest to go through the change logs. So is that file existing in your plugin? What is the complete path? And what are the first few lines of detail.htm.twig mentioned in the error trace?

Comment: Without seing code and the plugin, nobody can help you here. There were quite a lot of breaking changes within 6.4, because it was ja major update. As you can see within the error message the twig file can't be found. So I would double check the past etc.

Comment: Hello @Alex, It was Shopware6.3.5.4 now its updated into 6.4, the file (cms-section-half-width.html.twig) is there in the plugin at view>storefront>section. this error comes until the cache is not cleared, After cache cleared its all site gives. I have added the screeshot of that error too. ----HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
EMakersShoppingExperienceBlocks\Subscriber\ShoppingExperienceSubscriber::__construct(): Argument #2 ($salesChannelContextFactory) must be of type Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextFactory,

Comment: I have adjusted it as in hint, now it shows another error  Its already the type string. EMakersShoppingExperienceBlocks\Subscriber\ShoppingExperienceSubscriber::findMediaById(): Argument #1 ($mediaId) must be of type string, null given, called in /var/www/playground/custom/plugins/EMakersShoppingExperienceBlocks/src/Subscriber/ShoppingExperienceSubscriber.php on line 75

Comment: Check that line 75 and see what's happening there, probably something is not loaded properly

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes there was cache path problem, but now I have another problem which says sales-chanel-api route doesnt found, I know shopware6.4 has removed sales-channel api it has store -apri only but I am not aple to adjust it.

Comment: @Alex, I have added the new error screenshot above.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access? it sounds wrong...